# App crashes when perspective transform is applied on image

Tags: java, android, image, opencv

I am making an android app which takes an image through camera or gallery and detects sudoku( grid and numbers in it). I am using Android OpenCv for image processing. I am following these tutorials :- http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/sudoku-solver-part-3.html and http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/static/notebook/current/Sudoku_recognizer.html

Till now I have detect sudoku in a given image assuming sudoku is the largest rectangle in the given image.I am showing detected sudoku using colored lines on my original image. Now I have to apply perspective transform on the image. But when I do so and then apply the transformed image on image view of android, my app crashes. Please help me as I am new to both android and opencv.

Here is part of my MainActivity which deals with loading image from gallery and apply some image processing on it and finally displaying it on image view element. Part where code crashes is at last.

```
  else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        // cursor is basically used to connect our app with gallery app.
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //  img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);    // bitmap is a global variable to store images
        int height=550,width=550;

        int h=(int)Math.ceil(options.outHeight/(float)height);
        int w=(int)Math.ceil(options.outWidth/(float)width);

        if(h>1 || w>1){

            if(h>w)
                options.inSampleSize=h;
            else
                options.inSampleSize=w;

        }

        options.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);

        Log.d(TAG,"bitmap height: "+bitmap.getHeight());
        Log.d(TAG,"bitmap width: "+bitmap.getWidth());

        Mat imgGray = new Mat(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Mat thresh = imgGray;
        Mat mat = new Mat(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat);

        // Log.d(TAG, "Hello World");


        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, imgGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgGray, imgGray, new Size(5, 5), 0);
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imgGray, imgGray, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,15);

        Utils.matToBitmap(imgGray,bitmap);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

        Imgproc.findContours(imgGray.clone(), contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        //Utils.matToBitmap(imgNew,bitmap);
        //img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        MatOfPoint2f approxCurve=new MatOfPoint2f();


        //biggest rectangle
        double maxArea = 0;
        MatOfPoint biggestRect = new MatOfPoint();

        //   Log.d(TAG, "Hello");
        //  Log.d(TAG,"Number of contours in pic are: "+Integer.toString(contours.size()));

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i) {

            //convert MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f
            //Log.d(TAG,"Yo");
            //convert contours(i) from MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f

            double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));

            if(area>1000){


                MatOfPoint2f contour2f=new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray());
                double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true);

                Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f,approxCurve,approxDistance*0.08,true);

                MatOfPoint points=new MatOfPoint(approxCurve.toArray());

                Point[] pArray=points.toArray();
                //  Log.d(TAG,"Array of points has "+pArray.length+" points");

                if(area>maxArea && pArray.length==4){

                    biggestRect=points;
                    maxArea=area;
                }

            }

        }

        Log.d(TAG,Double.toString(maxArea));
        //  Log.d(TAG, "World");

        List<Point>source=biggestRect.toList();

        double maxiSum=-100000.0,miniSum=100000.0,maxiDiff=-100000.0,miniDiff=100000;
        Point topLeft=new Point(),topRight=new Point(),bottomLeft=new Point(),bottomRight=new Point();

        for(int i=0;i<source.size();++i){

            Point p1=source.get(i);
            Point p2=source.get((i+1)%source.size());

            Log.d(TAG,Double.toString(p1.x)+","+Double.toString(p1.y)+" "+Double.toString(p2.x)+","+Double.toString(p2.y));
            Core.line(mat,p1,p2,new Scalar(0,255,0),3);

            if(p1.x+p1.y>maxiSum){

                maxiSum=p1.x+p1.y;
                bottomRight=p1;

            }
            if(p1.x+p1.y<miniSum){

                miniSum=p1.x+p1.y;
                topLeft=p1;
            }

            if(p1.y-p1.x>maxiDiff){

                maxiDiff=p1.y-p1.x;
                bottomLeft=p1;
            }
            if(p1.y-p1.x<miniDiff){

                miniDiff=p1.x-p1.y;
                topRight=p1;
            }

        }

        Utils.matToBitmap(mat,bitmap);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        /*I sort my points in a definite order so that every image has
         definite order

             Top-Left, Top-Right,Bottom-Right,Bottom-Left
         */

        source=new ArrayList<Point>();

        source.add(topLeft);
        source.add(topRight);
        source.add(bottomRight);
        source.add(bottomLeft);


        for(int i=0;i<source.size();++i){

            Point p1=source.get(i);

            Log.d(TAG,"x coordinate: "+Double.toString(p1.x)+" y coordinate: "+Double.toString(p1.y));


        }


        List<Point>dest=new ArrayList<Point>();

        dest.add(new Point(0,0));
        dest.add(new Point(549,0));
        dest.add(new Point(549,549));
        dest.add(new Point(0,549));


        for(int i=0;i<dest.size();++i){

            Point p1=dest.get(i);

            Log.d(TAG,"x coordinate: "+Double.toString(p1.x)+" y coordinate: "+Double.toString(p1.y));


        }


        Mat startM= Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(source);
        Mat endM= Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(dest);


        Mat inputMat=new Mat(bitmap.getHeight(),bitmap.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC4);   // Colored
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap,inputMat);
        Mat outputMat=new Mat(550,550,CvType.CV_8UC4);

        /*
            App crashing starts from here. 

        */
        Mat perspectiveTranform=Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(startM,endM);

        Imgproc.warpPerspective(inputMat,outputMat,perspectiveTranform,new Size(550,550));

        Mat imgNewGray = new Mat(550,550,CvType.CV_8UC1);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(outputMat, imgNewGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

        Utils.matToBitmap(imgNewGray,bitmap);    // This is the line where app crashes.
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```

Here is my activity_main.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context="io.github.mayankpratap.pseudoku.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

  <Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Take pic using camera"
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      />

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Browse"
       android:id="@+id/browsebtn"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

   <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/loadbtn"
    android:text="load"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where exactly does it crash? Can you add logcat?

Comment: @Rick  App crashes in the last part of code where I apply perspective tranform to image and display it in image view.   Before that I detected sudoku in my image and displayed it using colored rectangle on image.

Comment: Can you give exact line? "last part of the code" can be misleading

Comment: @RickM. It starts from this line. Mat perspectiveTranform=Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(startM,endM);   After apply transform to image I am trying to set it in image view thats when app crashes. I have added comments to denote when app crashing starts.  Also I tried to add logcat but its exceeding the number of characters.

Comment: have you tried debugging the code? It can happen because of the size of the bitmap you convert it to when using _matToBitmap_. I would suggest adding only the relevant logcat, if it exceeding the number of characters add a printscreen (image) of the logcat